# Tears when using LAStools lassplit

Tags: qgis, lastools

I have just started using QGIS and im trying to create a DEM from laserdata using LAStools.
I have to split the laserdata since im not using a premium LAStools, but when i do i get these tears where the images dosent overlap/match up precise.

Does anyone know of this problem and how to solve it?

[image]